# Is it possible to CREATE and USE a SQL Server database in the same query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that initializes the database and tables for an application I'm creating. It starts out like

```
CREATE DATABASE snakedb; 

USE snakedb; 

CREATE TABLE scores ( id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                      name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL 
                    );

CREATE TABLE gamelogs ( scoreid INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES scores(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
                        logtxt VARCHAR (8000)
                       );
```

and won't execute because

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Database 'snakedb' does not exist.
>   Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Add a line with the following statement after the first: _GO_

Comment: How are you executing this SQL? In SSMS or through code?

Comment: @MartinSmith This is through SSMS.

Comment: So `GO` will work fine then.